# Scanning pencil sketches

Tags: sketching, wireframe

I do a lot of pencil and paper wireframing and would like to be able to faithfully scan my sketches. All my scans and photos have been terrible and I wonder if anybody else has faced and solved this problem.

EDIT:

Here's an example. This was from a page with a series of sketches using different graph types. I use mechanical pencils - 5mm and 9mm thickness in both red and black. The 9mm black comes out (poorly) and the 5mm red and black details do not appear at all.

[image]

Comment: looks like you need a better scanner? I usually just snap a photo with my phone.

Comment: I've used my phone as well and I'm dissatisfied with the results. I'm not putting these sketches in a book - they're just sketches but I do want to be able to see the details. My work scanner is terrible. I'm going to find a better scanner and get a grayscale tone ramp (as suggested in the forums.sijun post below) and give it another go.

Comment: use a marker instead of a pencil.

Comment: A comment to the moderators: I just found this, because I have a similar problem. Instead of just saying "question closed because off-topic", it would be much more useful to say where the question SHOULD be asked. Preferably with a link. This Stack Exchange is about user experience; and one way to improve that for your own site is not to make users search for stuff that you could easily tell them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also a common problem for digital artists with their pencil line work. You may have some luck doing a google search on "scanning sketches for digital work".

For me, if the lines are too faint and the BG too dark. I take it into photoshop and run a quick "level" adjustment. http://www.3dtotal.com/pages/tutorials/photoshop/levels_tutorial/levels.php

If you still have issues, try these tips:

From "Pat" http://forums.sijun.com/viewtopic.php?t=36848

> In any event, here's a few tips that might help you coax a little more detail out of your scanner:
>
> 1) Scan your pencil drawings in as a full color image. This gives you 3X the data over a simple grayscale image, it's like oversampling. The more data you get the better off you are when you try to adjust the image in Photoshop.
>
> 2) Purchase or make a grayscale tone ramp for inclusion with the scan. Lots of photography store sell these. Scan it along with the image. A lot of scanners have an auto-whitepoint/auto-contrast which will overexpose subtle tone. By including the tone ramp the scanner will not truncate the tonal range.
>
> 3) Some scanning software allows you to access the auto-whitepoint/auto-contrast features. Turn them off if possible. Always try to get raw scans whenever possible because Photoshop is far more capable at adjusting the values.
>
> 4) Always make sure your scanner is set to best quality. Sounds simple, but it's often overlooked. Also make sure it's warmed up if it requires it. A lot of scanners produce better scans once they've been scanning for a while.
>
> 5) For smaller drawings, scan them in your scanner's "sweet spot". You can find the sweet spot by scanning a variety of flat tonal images of the entire bed and then analyzing the scans in Photoshop. Scanners have difficulty with extremely light tones and extremely dark ones. Use the levels command to over or underexpose the scan. Those areas in "non-sweet spots" clip badly, as if there is a lot of detail missing. Areas with better preserved detail are your sweet spots.
>
> 6) learn to stich. I almost never use large flatbeds anymore. Sometimes you just have to, but a lot of images can be "stiched" togther in Photoshop. It takes some patience, good registration and a good eye for color balancing, but you can often times get better results that way. If quality is super-important take your image to a service bureau with a drum scanner.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at a lot of answer including the one from "Pat."  My lines don't come through very well. I'm reading through the 3Dtotal article now.

Comment: @Mayo Hmmm do you mind showing me one of your wireframe sketches?

Answer (score 2):

> I've used my phone as well and I'm dissatisfied with the results.

I'm not sure what you've tried with your phone, but using an app that lets you take photos and converts them into a color or greyscale 'scanned' image has worked well for me on pencil, whiteboard, and ink sketches.  I use TurboScan, which only has a 5-step contrast setting you can adjust for each image but on the 'darkest' setting it seems to pick up even light pencil marks okay.  You can probably do better with a better scanner and post-scan adjustment, but if you're just digitizing for posterity and personal or non-formal use, finding an app you like might be more efficient.

Here's an example of what I got with my normal overhead desk lighting with a standard wooden #2 pencil, red colored pencil, and a 0.5mm mechanical pencil.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I will take a look at it. I like the fact that you can see a change in line weight.

Answer (score 1):

With a HP Scanjet 5590P scanner I ticked a setting called Color Restoration and my pencil drawing scans became usable.

I had almost given up on this issue until I read nightning's answer who had referenced "Pat". I then tried all the options, just in case, but still nearly didn't try Color Restoration. Glad I did!

Answer (score 1):

2 point lighting, and photograph your work with a good camera. Scanning work is similar to flash photography, direct light and too much of it, creates reflections in the graphite and also blows out the white point.
The camera picks up the detail and then you can edit the rgb curve afterwards to accurately adjust the levels. But the detail is there.

I sketch predominately with hard pencils. This is the best option I have found so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sony Xperia phone which has an excellent camera. 
I then just use the built in photo editor in Google photos. 
If I up the contrast and fiddle with the whiteness they can look pretty good.

Only takes a few twiddles.

Very useful for building sketchy prototypes which I then do in balsamiq/invision

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the scanner. It worked wonderfully with many things but it could not pick up pencil marks well. The solution was to take photos with my phone.

Comment: Great - I find the phone works for many situations that I used to scan or write down stuff. Wierdly I really could not envision how useful it would be before it became the norm. Just shows how bad one can be at anticipating the future.

I now often take photos of old photos with my phone and touch them up. Sometimes I discover great unanticipated details in the shadows :-)